# Compute $I =\int_{0}^{\infty} exp\{-\frac{1}{2b}(y+b-c)^2\}dy+ \int_{-\infty}^{0} exp\{(-\frac{1}{2b}(y-b-c)^2\}dy, \quad b>0,\quad c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration

Compute $$I =\int_{0}^{\infty} exp\{-\frac{1}{2b}(y+b-c)^2\}dy+ \int_{-\infty}^{0} exp\{(-\frac{1}{2b}(y-b-c)^2\}dy, \quad b>0,\quad c\in\mathbb{R}$$

I am wondering if this integral can be computed? If there is some trick to get a pair of integrals with limits going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then I can use the result of the integral of a Gaussian function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also wonder how we could make it as someting looking like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots$.

However, each of the integrals can be computed using quite obvious changes of variable and the complementary error function
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\Big[-\frac{(y+b-c)^2}{2b}\Big]\,dy=\sqrt{\frac{b\pi }{2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{b-c}{\sqrt{2b}   }\right)$$
$$I_2=\int_{-\infty}^0 \exp\Big[-\frac{(y-b-c)^2}{2b}\Big]\,dy=\sqrt{\frac{b\pi }{2}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{2b}   }\right)$$

$$I_1+I_2=\sqrt{\frac{b\pi }{2}}  \left(\text{erfc}\left(\frac{b-c}{\sqrt{2b}
   }\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{2b} }\right)\right)$$